# Kivy TextInput Text Overflow. Cursor Outside TextInput Viewport

Tags: kivy

The last letter is overflowing

[image]

I'm using Kivy 1.10.1. I've added a text input (multiline = False). The sentence entered above is "This is a long sentence being typed into Kivy". All the letters have been entered. But the last letter - the "y" is outside the text input.
I've tried changing the padding size, the border size and changing the size of the textinput itself. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it is a bug with the library.

Edit:( I should have added the widget code here )

```
text_input: input_text_field

canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: self.background_color_intensity_red, self.background_color_intensity_green, self.background_color_intensity_blue, 1
    Rectangle:
        size: 396, 768
        pos: self.pos
        source: "sprites/phone.png"

BoxLayout:
    size: 354, 598
    pos: 21, 96
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.1
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        Image:
            size_hint: 0.15, 1
            source: "sprites/profile_pic.png"

        TextInput:
            id: input_text_field
            size_hint: 0.85, 0.5
            pos_hint: {'top': 0.75}
            background_color: 1,1,1,1
            border: (20, 20, 20, 20)
            multiline: False
            halign: 'center'
            focus: True
            on_text_validate: self.parent.parent.parent.on_text_input()

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.9
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Thank you.

Comment: If I remove the border attribute, the effect stays the same.

Comment: I see the same behavior. I think it is a bug in `TextInput`. Perhaps you could post an issue at [kivy github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy).